# How to change the name of Index section

Tags: indexing, naming

I use the `makeidx` in the `extreport` and the command `\printindex` to print the index out. The Index name (index in English) was translated to Vietnamese automatically into "Chỉ mục". I want to change "Chỉ mục" into "Tra cứu theo vần", which is much easier to understand in Vietnamse, my native language. So how can I do?

This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{extreport}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym,  amscd,amsfonts,enumerate,ifthen,stmaryrd,amsthm,amstext}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{graphics, graphpap,extsizes}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{perpage} 

\makeindex 

\begin{document}
\section*{Chuyển sang tứ giác} \index{hình vuông} 
\index{đối xứng trục}       

\index{đối xứng quay}

 Nhóm đối xứng \index{Nhóm đối xứng, i.e the symmetric group} của một tứ giác. 
\index{how can I do?} Ok let's see. 
\newpage 
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Here is the picture : 
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can either put

```
\renewcommand\indexname{Tra cứu theo vần}
```

after `\begin{document}` or

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\indexname{Tra cứu theo vần}}
```

in the preamble.

Note that placing the former in the preamble doesn't work since `vietnam.sty` has a line

```
\AtBeginDocument{\captionsvietnam\datevietnam}
```

which loads vietnamise names...

Comment: thanks a lot! it works `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\refname{Tài liệu tham khảo}}
`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `imakeidx` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\makeindex[title=Tra cứu theo vần]

\begin{document}
\section*{Chuyển sang tứ giác} \index{hình vuông}
\index{đối xứng trục}

\index{đối xứng quay}

 Nhóm đối xứng \index{Nhóm đối xứng, i.e the symmetric group} của một tứ giác.
\index{how can I do?} Ok let's see.

\newpage

\printindex
\end{document}
```

This will also free you from the burden of running MakeIndex, because the package does it by itself. Moreover it allows building as many indices as you want.

Comment: I find this `imakeidx` package solution more powerful than the traditional `\renewcommand\indexname{}` option (though I am not I fan of abusing the use of extra packages). In the latter case, the renaming of the index is separated from the call to `\makeindex`, even worse it is in the body of the document, whereas with `imakeidx`, it all remains compact, together: It results in better portability to other documents, and less chances to mess up. +1